# Редирект со страницы на поддомен

Tags: редирект

Поддомены на сайте доступны и по адрессу "сайт.ру/поддомен" подскажите как настроить редирект чтоб такие страницы перенаправлялись на "поддомен.сайт.ру"
и страницы "сайт.ру/поддомен/страница" перенаправлялись на "поддомен.сайт.ру/страница" 
в htaccess